# Expand/Collapse not working for certain browsers

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

In Chrome the expand/collapse button, seen [here](http://staging.openingdesign.com/projects/585), work fine. (1st image).

However, in firefox, there's a weird overlap problem, as see in the (2nd image).

Been trying desperately for days to figure out why.  Was wondering if anyone might have a suggested clue to solve.

### In Chrome...

[image]

### In Firefox...

[image]

Comment: It is always preferable to post your code in your question, in addition to linking to a working example. This is because external websites may change later on while this question remains on the site.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your animation, the height of the child is set to "auto" on Chrome but to "0px" on Firefox. If you remove manually this value, it works. Does your script works differently depending on the browser?